# Adding accessibility identifier to a substring of an NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, accessibility, nsattributedstring

I'm attempting to configure a `NSMutableAttributedString` on a `UILabel`'s `attributedText` property to display accessibility identifiers for links within the attributed string.

### Objective

- `UILabel` with `NSAttributedString` that's got a clickable link which opens a URL and...
- Has an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the link that Appium/VoiceOver can find.

### What's Happening Now

Right now, the links display as expected, but when I view them with the Accessibility Inspector, it sees them as a single element, however I can click the links and they open the URL as expected. This is the implementation for the extension I'm using to add a link:

```swift
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    @discardableResult
    public func setLink(for text: String,
                        linkURL: String) -> Bool {
        guard let url = URL(string: linkURL) else { return false }
        let linkRange = self.mutableString.range(of: text)

        guard linkRange.location != NSNotFound else { return false }

        self.addAttribute(.link,
                          value: url,
                          range: linkRange)

        // This doesn't do anything :(
        self.addAttribute(.accessibilityTextCustom,
                          value: text,
                          range: linkRange)
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
    private lazy var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = {
        let string = "CNN and ESPN"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

        attributedString.setLink(for: "CNN", linkURL: "https://www.cnn.com")
        attributedString.setLink(for: "ESPN", linkURL: "https://www.espn.com")

        return attributedString
    }()

    myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Looking through documentation, I see [`accessibilityLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key), which seems like it would get the job done, but it's for MacOS 10.4+, not iOS. Any thoughts on how to get an accessibility identifier on a substring of an `NSMutableAttributedString` that shows up in Appium/Accessibility Inspector?

If that's not the way to go, is there a way to do this with an accessibility container?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/2865944-accessibilityattributedlabel maybe ?

Comment: @Larme Oh...are you thinking right on the `UILabel`, not the `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. I don't use Accessibility, but seeing `Update Your App’s Accessibility` on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app and searching NSAttributedString + Accessibility seems to point on that property

Comment: Seems it would be good to file a feedback report as this has long been a gap